# mktime() не корректно считает время

Tags: php, время

Не могу понять, почему функция

```
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1970);
```

возвращает значение "-10800" (ошибка в 3 часа), хотя должна возвращать 0 секунд.
Ответа нигде найти не могу, подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Потому что mktime принимает на вход **местное** время, и когда в вашем месте наступает полночь 1970 года, в Лондоне (UTC) всё ещё 21 час вечера 1969 года — ровно на 10800 секунд меньше чем в вашем местном времени

Comment: Ну и на всякий случай напомню, что mktime возвращает метку времени Unix, а метка времени Unix начинает свой отсчёт от полуночи по UTC, то есть по Лондону

Comment: @andreymal, просто еще месяц назад такой проблемы не было. Но ладно.
Получается, при работе с mktime() нужно добавлять 10800, что бы возвращались корректные значения?

Comment: И если вдруг часовой пояс внезапно изменится (как вариант, если в России вернут переход на летнее время), то вы замучаетесь постоянно исправлять эти 10800 на правильное актуальное число. Лучше расскажите, какую задачу вы вообще решаете?

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю за разъяснения!

Comment: @andreymal, пока только изучаю азы PHP и программирования по бесплатным курсам. Задача стояла в написании класса, который в конструкторе принимал две даты, методами toDays, toMonths, toYears возвращал разницу между датами в днях, месяцах и годах соответственно. И вот, высчитывая разницу между двумя датами без учёта 10800 секунд в методе toDays, был озадачен тем, что возвращалось не целое число.

Comment: @andreymal, такой код был:
    `public function toDays(): int
    {
        $firstTotalS = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int)$this->firstDay->format("m"), (int)$this->firstDay->format("d"), (int)$this->firstDay->format("Y"));
        $secondTotalS = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int)$this->secondDay->format("m"), (int)$this->secondDay->format("d"), (int)$this->secondDay->format("Y"));

        if ($firstTotalS >= $secondTotalS){
            return ($firstTotalS - $secondTotalS) / (60*60*24);
        }
        return ($secondTotalS - $firstTotalS) / (60*60*24);
    }`

Comment: Здесь критически важно то, в каком именно часовом поясе задаются эти две даты - в зависимости от пояса разница будет разной даже для одинаковых дат. Но если дата местная - то просто используйте mktime и не парьтесь (и не надо лепить никакие 10800, для подсчёта разницы это не имеет значения)

Comment: @andreymal, да дело в том, что тогда при переводе из секунд в дни результат получается не целый

Comment: Если разница между датами и правда не является целым числом дней в местном часовом поясе, то вполне логично, что результат будет не целый — это правильное поведение

Answer (score 0):

Функция mktime() возвращает Unix timestamp, то есть количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года до указанной даты и времени. В вашем случае вы указываете час, минуту и секунду равными 0, то есть указываете, что нужно посчитать секунды от полуночи 1 января 1970 до полуночи 1 января 1970. Таким образом, функция должна вернуть 0 секунд.

Однако функция mktime() возвращает значение -10800, что соответствует 3 часам в секундах. Это может быть связано с тем, что сервер, на котором вы выполняете эту функцию, находится в таймзоне, отличной от UTC (координированного мирового времени). В этом случае функция mktime() учитывает разницу между таймзоной сервера и UTC и возвращает корректное значение Unix timestamp для указанной даты и времени в таймзоне сервера.

Чтобы исправить эту проблему и получить 0 секунд в качестве результата работы функции mktime(), вы можете указать таймзону UTC в качестве параметра для функции date_default_timezone_set(), чтобы указать, что все даты и время, указываемые в скрипте, должны быть в таймзоне UTC. Например:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1970);
```

Таким образом, функция mktime() будет возвращать 0 секунд, так как указанная дата и время соответствуют полуночи 1 января 1970 в таймзоне UTC.

Однако следует отметить, что функция mktime() может возвращать отрицательные значения, если указанная дата и время раньше 1 января 1970 в таймзоне UTC. Например, результатом работы функции mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1969) будет отрицательное число, соответствующее количеству секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 янва